# Display output with QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget

I am trying to load some file names read from a directory and put it into the `QListWidget`.

Though it works, there is 2 problems...
Example, the first 3 items are called: `apple, pear and banana`

Instead of displaying my info in the `ListWidget` as horizontal in 3 rows, mine was display in multiple rows, with each letter occupying a row...

```
def fillJobsList(self):
for shot in shots:
self.jobShotsList.addItems(str(shot))
```

`jobShotsList` is the name of my `QListWidget`.

My second problem is that I am unable to clear the contents in my `QListWidget`.

```
self.fillJobsList.clear()
```

This is the code I used, but as soon as I execute it, it is not even able to display the contents resulting in an error...

Can someone guide me?

Comment: Your spelling is not correct, you missed **s** from `self.jobShotsList.clear()` :)

Answer (score 0):

shot ist the list? Remove str

```
self.jobShotsList.addItems(shot)
```

I think this should work.

Comment: Turns out I must type it as: self.jobShotsList.addItems(shots) instead of shot due to the QString of addItems...

Answer (score 0):

1. `addItems (self, QStringList labels)` needs a list of string, but you passed a `str(shot)` to it, which is also an iterable. Thus, use `.addItems(yourItemList)` or `.addItem(yourItem)` in a for loop instead.
2. could you paste the traceback when you get error using `.clear` ?

**update:**
just as @qurban mentioned, you missed a `s` in your code, it's `jobShotsList`, not `jobShotList`. In this case, you'd better code with some IDE or text editor with code auto-completion.

Comment: I have solved my problem for the first part but as for the .clear, I am still getting the problem.

Error message is 'function' object has no attribute 'clear'

Comment: Hi sorry about that, I should have made my codes clearer. Pertaining to the one you mentioned, there is indeed that problem as well... And there is a typo too in my message...

I am trying to make fillJobsList.clear() but it didn't work at all

    def fillJobsList(self):
    for shot in shots:
            self.jobShotsList.addItems(shots)